# jquery plugin syntax

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a jquery plugin, and I want have the following options:

1. `$.plugin_name(variable)`
2. `$(selector).plugin_name(variable)`

The first case the plugin would not need to be applied to an element ( it could create one for example) the second case the same plugin will do whatever it does on the element/s selected

My question is: How do I specify inside the plugin this:

```
if (selector is not given) {
  create an element
} else {
  ( for example) insert variable in elements matching the selector
}
```

Comment: I was actually wondering if there was a way to author a plugin that would do both...
in case no selector is given it would create an element...so ideally it can be called both as $.pluginName() or $(selector).pluginName() not either or .
thank you

Comment: It is not possible, at least that's my understanding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I'd like to understand the jQuery plugin syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484289/id-like-to-understand-the-jquery-plugin-syntax)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.fn.myPluginName = function()....` for plugins that operate on jQuery objects.

For a standalone function in the `jQuery` namespace, you can just set `jQuery.func_name = function()...`.

An example:

```
jQuery.fn.erase = function() {
   return this.each(function() {
       jQuery(this).remove();
   });
};

jQuery("body").erase();

jQuery.erase = function(element) {
   jQuery(element).erase();
};

jQuery.erase("body"); // exact same result.
```

Answer (score 4):

By using `$.myFunc` you are simply adding a function to the jQuery namespace.

By using `$.fn.myFunc`, you are extending the jQuery prototype, which means that the **this** keyword inside the function will represent the jQuery object returned from the selector.

If you'd like them both to do the same thing, you can check for the jQuery instance and create a new element:

**try this:**

```
$.myFunc = $.fn.myFunc = function(first, second) {
    if (!(this instanceof $)) {
        return $.fn.myFunc.apply($('<div>'), arguments);
    }
    // begin plugin code here:
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).text(first + ' ' + second);
    });
};

// now you can call myFunc in two ways:

$('<div>').myFunc('foo','bar').appendTo('body') 

$.myFunc('bar','foo').appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 2):

To cover `$.plugin_name()` use:

```
jQuery.plugin_name = function(data) {
  // do stuff
}
```

For `$(selector).plugin_name()` use:

```
jQuery.fn.plugin_name = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    // do stuff
  });
};
```

See [Plugins/Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).