# jquery plugin syntax wrapper

Tags: jquery

What exactly does this do?  I know that it gets wrapped around jquery plugins, but have no real understanding of what it does.

```
(function ($, undefined) {

// Plugin goes here

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I'd like to understand the jQuery plugin syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484289/id-like-to-understand-the-jquery-plugin-syntax)

Comment: Yes, the answer there covers it pretty well.

Comment: Yes, it covers pretty well but here you can see use of `undefined` like a variable which is not passed to function for a reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`()()` is a way to run a piece of code in javascript. The first pair of parentesis is the code part and the second is for execute order and you can pass variables like calling a function.

Within first parentesis you define your function, which takes two arguments and you execute it with a parameter `jQuery` which is core jQuery object. To do so, you are passing jQuery object to your function as a variable and name it `$`. Because your function is defined in that scope your code doesn't conflict with another `$` variable on global scope or scope that contains your code.

As you can see there is another variable: `undefined` but no parameter for it. By not passing a second parameter second variable will be undefined and because it's name is undefined you can use it in your code freely. For more info about undefined you can look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_undefined.asp)

I hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 3):

That creates a scope that you can define variables and methods in without fear of them being exposed to the global scope.

There are many articles floating around going into far more detail than this.

Edit: here's one http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/