# Understanding JavaScript functions and plugins set up

Tags: jquery-plugins, javascript

I have just started to write JavaScript after some time and I am confused by plugins constructor set up. I went through this link for advice.

[What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

I am interested in understanding this function set up..

I have seen seen three examples like this below:

```
(function(parameterOne, parameterTwo) {

    functionOne = function(...) {
       ...
   },

   functionTwo: new function() {
   },

   this.functionThree = function(...) {
   }

})()
```

My questions are as follows:

1. When do one use the construct as given for functionOne vs functionTwo vs functionThree? How would I be able to call the functionOne, functionTwo or functionThree explicitly?
2. I have seen functions like this:

   ```
   (function(parameter) {

       functionFour = function(..) {
      },
      ....
   })(document)
   ```

What does the **document** in this example indicate? I have been confused about this for a long time now.

3. I have seen jQuery plugins that follow this structure?

   ```
   (function($) {

     $.fn.myCustomPlugin: function(...) {
     }
   })(jQuery)
   ```

Why is **$** passed to the function and **jQuery** passed at the end? I apologize as this may be rudimentary questions to some of you but these have stymied me for couple of weeks now and I am desperate to get any answers I can.

Thanks,

Kartik

Comment: see this post...and follow links to other duplicates within it  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894038/jquery-plugin-syntax-wrapper   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484289/id-like-to-understand-the-jquery-plugin-syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(function(parameterOne, parameterTwo) {`

Does not make sense as you're not passing these arguments in the end. Also, looks like you're immediately trying to create anonymous code block - makes sense in some cases, but you don't need to do it unless you're trying to protect global scope from whatever happens inside this code block.

```
    functionOne = function(...) {
       ...
   },
```

This is a named function similar to `var functionOne` will be useful only inside parent function or constructor.

```
   functionTwo: new function() {
   },
```

**UPDATE:** Doesn't really make sense as you're trying to create instance here. You can definitely immediately instantiate what you have inside that function declaration (it is same as declaring a func. first and then using operator `new`) but in this case what you get is an object not a function. Try:

```
var f = function() {};
console.log(f); // "function"
var f = new function() {}
console.log(f); // "objest"
```

That object is the instance of your constructor function.

```
   this.functionThree = function(...) {
   }
```

this is a method of a class. Once you instantiate the class using operator `new`, you can access it from outside of the instance. Also when you use `this.` inside a class, remember that every time you instantiate a class, it will reserve memory for this value. When the variable is different for these instances than it's okay, but if it's a method, you're better of adding it to the constructor prototype, this way it's only declared once and new memory chunks are not reserved for it.

```
})()
```

here you would ordinarily pass params you request inside, e.g. `parameterOne, parameterTwo`

```
(function(parameter) {

    functionFour = function(..) {
   },
   ....
})(document)
```

This is a way to pass context or any objects to this anonymous code block. In this case it looks like a plug in that takes window.document but it can also take any other part of DOM. For instance, if you want to select all tags `a` and receive `document` as param, it will iterate through all links in window.document, but if you pass `$('#somediv')`, this plugin will iterate through links only inside div with this id.

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.myCustomPlugin: function(...) {
  }
})(jQuery)
```

This is a good way to make sure that in the code inside $ is a jQuery object. Thing is that in Chrome for example there's already a native function `$`, or in some production sites `$` may be a Prototype JS function. But in the example inside you make sure that var `$` is not native `$` or not Prototype.

In general, you should not use `(function() {...})()` liberally -- this is only used in specific cases when you're protecting global environment as I mentioned above.

Comment: My examples were possible wrong or incorrect because I don't know javascript that well. I am learning as I go but that is why I asked this question.

Comment: I get it, I did not mean to be critical at all, I am just explaining what you got there :)

Comment: May I ask how would I invoke the functions functionOne, functionTwo, and functionThree, if at all possible?

Comment: if invoke function by using `()` after function name, e.g. `functionOne()` and by using `call` or `apply` methods. You can get an instance of a function, which is a JS object, by using keyword `new`. Remember that what you get by doing that is an object, not a function. In your example invocation for all of them is same -- `functionOne(args)` or `functionTwo.call(args)` or `this.functionThree.apply(args)`.