# Jquery no conflict

Tags: jquery

For the most part .noConflict() is working fine for me, for example:

```
$jq('#no-thanks').click( function(event) {
    $jq("#olsu").fadeOut();             
});
```

but what is the syntax for this:

```
$.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 7 });
```

I've tried:

```
$jq.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 7 })
```

and

```
$jq().cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 7 })
```

any ideas?

Comment: please post your HTML as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
(function($){
  // your all jQuery code inside here

  $.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 7 });

})(jQuery);
```

Now you can use `$` without fear of conflicting with other libraries as long as you put your jQuery code in above self-invoking anonymous function.

[More Explanation Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484289/id-like-to-understand-the-jquery-plugin-syntax/4484317#4484317)

Answer (score 2):

You *have* added the `jquery.cookie.js` script to your page right?

`jQuery.cookie` is not a native jQuery function, so you need to make sure that it's being added, and that it's being correctly added to jQuery if it's happening after `noConflict` was called.

As for aliasing jQuery, you can use a self-executing anonymous function to alias `jQuery` to `$` safely. Additionally the `document.ready` shortcut also can be used to alias `jQuery` to `$`:

```
(function ($) {
  //code goes here
}(jQuery));

jQuery(function ($) {
  //document.ready code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
jQuery.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 7 })
```

Also you can simplyfy your life by wrapping your code in anonymous function and passing jQuery to it:

```
(function($){
  $('#no-thanks').click( function(event) {
    $("#olsu").fadeOut();             
    $.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 7 });

  });
})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling jQuery directly?

```
jQuery.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 7 })
```

Comment: but cookie is undefined in jquery core and thats the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got `$jq`, but the jQuery object is `jQuery`, so:

```
jQuery.cookie("example", "foo", {expires: 7});
```

Comment: You can store the no conflict jQuery variable into anything you wish: `$jq = jQuery.noConflict();`