# jQuery not working on my Drupal page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drupal, drupal-7

Here is the live page I am trying to implement on my Drupal website:

[Working Page](http://www.crm-newsletter.com/website/mortgagePlannerCRM.html)

This page works perfectly fine and uses the same versions of jQuery and jQueryUI that Drupal 7 uses.

Now when I put this content onto my Drupal site located here:

[Drupal Page - Not working](http://mpc.demosite.us/mortgageplannercrm.html)

jQueryUI seems to be not working. The jQuery Rotate is working fine however.

I've been searching for answers and implemented several methods, all of which have failed including the method of wrapping my jQuery in this code:

```
(function($) {

})(jQuery);
```

Any help as soon as possible would be amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty obscure. My code called for jquery 1.7 so that's what I had loaded up. On a hunch, I changed it back to Drupal's default jQuery 1.5 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're doing (according what I see on your html code)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
...
})(jQuery);
```

That is incorrect. Try with this

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
    ...
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484289/id-like-to-understand-the-jquery-plugin-syntax/4484317#4484317) popular question in order to get more details about the correct syntax.

Comment: That's giving me a syntax error in Dreamweaver and disables everything on my page now, including the jQuery Rotate.

Comment: Oh I see, you forgot the first open bracket. But still, this did not fix the problem. Exact same results.

Comment: @TommyCoffee: sorry, I missed a `{` after `(function($)`. Please try again

Comment: @Tommy Coffee: I easily found the problem I solved on my answer because it was generating a js error, unfortunately now we don't have any quick indicator of problems. I'd have to review all the code and unfortunately I don't have the time now.